# Default Virtual Host not catching the request

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have an Apache 2.4 server with two enabled virtual hosts:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-website.conf

```
<VirtualHost my-website.com:80>
    ServerAdmin myself@my-website.com
    ServerName my-website.com
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://my-website.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost my-website.com:443>
    ....
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I created a domain name pointing to the same machine: my-other-website.com.

When I issue an http request (browser, curl,...) on my-other-website.com, I would expect it to serve the default virtual host. Instead, I get 301 redirected to `https://my-website.com/`.

How come?

Changing `<VirtualHost *:80>` into `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualHost marching is a bit peculiar and particular.

The “problem” is that you mix a `*:80` with `hostname:80` and the latter is the preferred match when a request for that ip-address & port number combination is received.

And *:80 is only the default VirtualHost for requests that don’t have the same ip-address as your my-website.com domain.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html#hostmatching

> When the connection is first received on some address and port, the server looks for all the VirtualHost definitions that have the same IP address and port.
>
> If there are no exact matches for the address and port, then wildcard (*) matches are considered.
>
> If no matches are found, the request is served by the main server.
>
> If there are VirtualHost definitions for the IP address, the next step is to decide if we have to deal with an IP-based or a name-based vhost.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it. So what's the point of the hostname in <VirtualHost hostname:80> if only ServerName/ServerAlias is used to match the request?

Comment: It is intended to bind  virtual hosts to specific ip-address/port combinations and that allows Apache httpd both ip-based VirtualHosting (which is not that common a requirement anymore this day and age but was pretty useful with SSL before SNI , for HTP 1.0 clients) and allows different default virtualhosts for each ip-address on a server

Answer (score 2):

Make both virtual hosts as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

However i would use an IP for both hosts, it can be same IP  `<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>`

Comment: That would indeed be a solution